# Can a callback to onMessageExternal.addListener be async?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension running along with a simple webpage. I send a message to the extension, at which point the extension does something async. The below code doesn't work because the callback on `sendMessage` immediately fires, before my promise resolves. Is there any way around this? Or do I need to manually send a message back from the extension to the browser?

Webpage:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, {action: "share"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  // var promise = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true, video:true});
});
```

Extension:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (request.action === 'share') {
      chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(["screen","window"], (streamId, options) =>{
        resolve(streamId);
      });
    } else {
      reject('Bad action');
    }
  }).then(resp => {
    sendResponse(resp);
  });
});
```

Comment: Why not wrap your function inside another promise so you can control it with `.then`?

Comment: You have to add `return true;` to your listener function if you are going to call `sendResponse` asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessageExternal), the `sendResponse` function

> becomes invalid when the event listener returns, **unless you return true** from the event listener to indicate you wish to send a response asynchronously (this will keep the message channel open to the other end until sendResponse is called)

Therefore, your extension code would be something like:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (request.action === 'share') {
      chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(["screen","window"], (streamId, options) =>{
        resolve(streamId);
      });
    } else {
      reject('Bad action');
    }
  }).then(resp => {
    sendResponse(resp);
  });

  return true;  //<-- add this

});
```